# WebStorm 2016.2.4 does not use @types definition

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm trying to switch from Definitelytyped definition files to @types packages. After adding all the necessary dependencies to my package.json file, I am compiling with absolutely no error.

The problem is that the WebStorm 2016.2.4 does use the @types definition files: I got many 'unresolved...' errors.
I cannot find any setting in the IDE to let it use them...

I do not know if there could be any link with my problem: my project include both a node/express server written in TypeScript with its own package.json file and node_modules in one directory and an Angular 2 application with also a package.json/node_modules.

The tsconfig.json is common for both of them and I use an external TypeScript compiler (2.0.6).

Thanks for any idea !

Comment: Ran in to the same issue and decided to defer using @types. One option could be to use VS code: https://code.visualstudio.com/ untl WebStorm supports the new typings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your node_modules folders as a library. Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries